# Finding a generator for a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory

Suppose $\mathcal A\subset\mathcal P(X)$ is some $\sigma$-algebra on a set $X$. Is there some $G\subset \mathcal P(X)$ such that $\mathcal A=\sigma(G)$ and $G\ne\mathcal A$? In other words, can we find a non-trivial generator for any $\sigma$-algebra on $X$, or can there be some $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ which can only be trivially generated by themselves? In the case that such $\sigma$-algebras exist, are there general rules or structures that classify them?

**Edit 1:**

From a discussion in the comments, it became clear to me that $\sigma(\mathcal A-\{0\})=\mathcal A$ is a rather trivial example of such a sought-after generator. With this in mind, I would like to exclude this case from my question as well. Furthermore, again inspired by the comments, one could wonder what other elements could be removed from $\mathcal A$ such that the resulting set generates $\mathcal A$. In other words, what sets $K\subset\mathcal A$ satisfy $\sigma(\mathcal A-K)=\mathcal A$? And what would be such a maximal set $K$? Intuitively, I would say that from a finitely generated $\sigma$-algebra, no elements can be removed except $\{0\}$, although I'm not sure how to prove that. Also, I suppose that there must be some additional structure on an infinite $\mathcal A$ to say something about the set $K$, but again, I don't know where to start.

**Edit 2:**

Clearly, $X$ could be removed from $\mathcal A$ instead of $\emptyset$. I suppose that if $\mathcal A$ is not trivial, then both could be always removed as well.

Comment: Just delete the empty set, or something like that.

Comment: $\sigma$-algebras have a lot of closure properties... it's pretty easy to just delete a few things and have it regenerate itself. (Or a lot of things.. like take the Borel sigma algebra and delete anything that isn't an interval with rational endpoints.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I suppose removing the empty set would work. The smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing itself but the empty set would be itself again, that makes sense. It is an answer to my question but... it's rather boring. We could always remove the empty set. I wonder if there is some less trivial way to remove things. Looking at your second comment, I'm wondering what some "maximal" deleting would look like such that the $\sigma$-algebra retains its structure.

Comment: This strikes me as one of those situations where the boring counterexample (and the many boring derivatives of the boring counterexample) just underscores the fact that this property is badly broken, but perhaps I shouldn't have written the answer since it's possible there's something more interesting to be said. In regards to your new question, there is some information [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/168535/minimal-generator-of-an-algebra-or-a-sigma-algebra).

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thank you for directing me to that page. As for your answer, please consider taking another look at my question, as I have made an addition to it in accorance with our discussion.

Comment: You can keep removing a lot of things. For instance, at any point, as long as a set's complement remains, you can definitely remove it. The question of whether there's a maximal set you can remove is equivalent to whether there's a minimal generating set.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Yes, I see. According to the link you presented me with, not every $\sigma$-algebra has a minimal generator. That answers the question I had in mind!

Comment: Yep, but countably generated ones do (so e.g. the Borel $\sigma$-algebra does).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. For any $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$ we have $\sigma(\Sigma-\{\emptyset\}) = \Sigma.$